# Pagination showing no entries after first page

Tags: channel-entries, pagination

We have a blog section on our website that displays 10 entries per page however, when you click next page or '2' it returns an empty page.

From what I can see the code is the same as for our news page and that's working fine. I've looked through similar issues on the forums but can't find a fix that works.

The code for the entries is:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" orderby="date" paginate="bottom" limit="10" {if segment_2}author_id="{segment_2}"{/if}  dynamic="no"}
```

And the code for the pagination is:

```
{paginate}

<p class="pagination">Showing page {current_page} of {total_pages} <span>{pagination_links}</span></p>
{/paginate}
```

Can anyone see what would be causing the issue?

Let me know if there's any more info you'd need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{if segment_2}author_id="{segment_2}"{/if}
```

There's your problem. After you click on a pagination link, `{segment_2}` becomes `P10`, `P20`, etc. So you're looking for all entries by the member with the ID of `P10`.

You're better off making an `author` template to filter entries by author, where you can have a more predictable segment to hold the member ID and still use pagination.

Comment: Thanks Derek, I hadn't realised that was what that related to, I'm sure it hadn't caused an issue until recently though which seems strange. I've changed the author_id to `{segment_3}` and amended the code for the authors section to the following `{exp:top_authors channel="blog"} <li><a href="/blog/author/{author_id}">{name} ({count})</a> </li> {/exp:top_authors}` adding in the `/author/` segment after the `/blog/` and this has fixed the issue, pagination works and the author filter works. Do you think writing it like this could cause any other issues?

Comment: That looks right to me!